# flipped image in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Im trying to plot an image using matplotlib, and it comes out rotated 90 degrees clockwise, which  seems to be a common problem. So i need to rotate it back 90 degrees counterclockwise to show my actual image. However when I tried to plot the transpose of the data, i get an error message that says "invalid dimensions for image data" additionally i also tried to set origin to lower because that also seems to be a way to fix such problems, but that only flipped it across the x axis.  How do I fix this? here is my original code

```
from dipy.reconst.dti import color_fa
cfa = color_fa(FA, tenfit.evecs)
cfa_img = nib.Nifti1Image(cfa.astype(np.float32), img.get_affine())
data_cfa = cfa_img.get_data()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure('color_fa')
plt.imshow(data_cfa[:,:,6,:])
plt.show()
```

so it shows slice 6 of an image which is 192x192

and when i change the imshow line to

```
plt.imshow(data_cfa[:,:,6,:].T)
```

i get that error message.

I'm new to python and matplotlib, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are trying to transpose an image with three dimensions. The dimensions of your image are N x M x 3, and you would like to have a M x N x 3 array (rotate but keep the color planes intact).

With the `.T` method you'll unfortunately get an array with dimensions 3 x M x N, which is not what you want. This is the source of the error.

Instead of `.T` use `.transpose(1,0,2)`.This will transpose the two first axes but leaves the third intact. Now the image should be rotated as you wanted it:

```
plt.imshow(data_cfa[:,:,6,:].transpose(1,0,2))
```

See the documentation for `np.transpose`: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html

(If your image were a N x M grayscale image, then the `.T` trick would have been the right one.)

Answer (score 1):

Try `scipy.ndimage.rotate` (see example code below). Unlike `.T` which swaps all the axes (see answer from @DrV), `ndimage.rotate` is designed to leave the color information alone. It can also handle an arbitrary rotation (e.g. 31.4 degrees). For a broader range of examples look at http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/image_processing/#geometrical-transformations.

```
data_cfa = rand(10,10,7,3)

plt.subplot(211)
plt.imshow(data_cfa[:,:,6,:])
plt.title('Original')

plt.subplot(212)
plt.imshow(ndimage.rotate(data_cfa[:,:,6,:], 90))
plt.title('Rotated by 90')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well answer the question - but a bit of explanation is always appreciated, rather than just a block of code :) don't forget that lots of newbies come to S/O and they may not understand what you have changed or why. They could learn from your expertise if you tell them :)